How to show ProgressBar with Percentage Api Response Time?
I Want to show ProgressBar With a Percentage Until Api is SuccessFully Called. How can I set Progress with the amount of Percentage by changing Text to 100 % and also Progressbar dismiss after 100 Percent?

Any idea how to do it, if anyone knows about it please let me know.
